# How do I specify additional directories for a linker in a cl compiler

Tags: windows, linker, cl

I use the `cl /EHsc fileName.cpp` command in powershell to compile cpp files, and the thing is I cannot find on the web how to specify the paths to additional dependencies for a linker to know where to look for lib files. Same goes with headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-170).

```
cl /I c:\myheaders /I ..\onemore mycode.c /link /LIBPATH:.\foo /LIBPATH:c:\bar
```